# For which increments in a velocity distribution does the temperature change?

Tags: thermodynamics

I was discussing with a friend the fact that adding infinitesimally small amounts of heat to a system would not alter its temperature, and that was why that process was reversible. But then that got me thinking. Temperature is proporcional to the expected value of the velocity distribution squared. Can there exist a non-infinitesimal real number such that adding that number someway in the distribution doesn't disturb the global temperature?. In other words, consider a system $S$ in thermodynamic equilibrium and the function:
$$T(v(x,y,z,t))=k\langle v^2\rangle$$
Where $v$ is the velocity distribution in function of every point in $S$ and the time $t$, $k$ is some constant and $\frac{dT}{dt}=0$. Can there be a real number $\Delta v$ such that perturbing the distribution $v$ at a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0,t_0)$  mantains $\frac{dT}{dt}=0$? And if so, can we estimate it?

Comment: It is not clear why do you think that even a tiny flux of heat does not change the temperature. In general, it does, but in the presence of a first-order phase transition.

Comment: @GiorgioP I was following the same logic as in quasistatic processes. An infinitesimal increment of heat would make the prior state and the perturbed state indistinguishable.